# Deploying selenium project with Java & geckodriver for firefox on remove server .

Tags: selenium, webdriver, geckodriver

I am working on a selenium project with geckodriver for firefox. Now I am in phase to deploy my code on a remote server. wondering what steps should I follow?
Can Geckodriver.exe be included in runnable jars or should I just add it in folder.
Do I need to run Geckodriver.exe on remove to make it work?

Comment: Use Maven. See https://github.com/Ardesco/selenium-standalone-server-plugin

Answer (score 0):

You can just add your geckodriver.exe into your project folder.You can create bash or python script to run that project.So that you can give proper permission on that folder.

Comment: Thanks, I am not sure what server will be allocated to me and whether it will have mozilla browser or not, do I need to install mozilla on remove server separately?

Comment: You can put your .exe in your project. Script will do the rest to load that browser.

Answer (score 0):

Create a folder in your project with name "drivers" and drop gecko driver in it and from the code you can use System.getProperty("user.dir"+"/drivers/geckodriver.exe") to get the location of the driver. This approach will work no matter where the code is

Comment: Thank you... I am not sure what server will be allocated to me and whether it will have mozilla browser or not, do I need to install mozilla on remove server separately?

Comment: i guess once you install mozilla you dont need to do it again as it is a one time task and once mozilla is installed you are good to go